# How to define 2048-bit integers on smart contracts?

Tags: solidity, cryptography, bignumber

As we know solidity supports only 256-bit big integers. But for crypto primitives (sometimes) we need bigger integers, e.g. 2048-bit.

**Question**: how can we define 2048-bit integers on a smart contract and perform some modular operations on that size integers?

Comment: Well, you can use a `uint256` array with 8 entries.

Answer (score 4):

I would try to recreate the operations with an array of `uint128`. To make it simpler, let's say we want to do it for 512-bit integers:

```
// With the large number = num[0] + 2^128 * num[1] + 2^256 * num[2] + 2^384 * num[3]
function add(uint128[4] num1, uint128[4] num2) public pure returns(uint128[4] sum) { 
    uint256[4] memory intermediaries;
    intermediaries[0] = (uint256) (num1[0]) + (uint256) (num2[0]);
    intermediaries[1] = (uint256) (num1[1]) + (uint256) (num2[1]);
    intermediaries[2] = (uint256) (num1[2]) + (uint256) (num2[2]);
    intermediaries[3] = (uint256) (num1[3]) + (uint256) (num2[3]);
    uint256 shifter = 2**128;
    uint256 lowerMask = shifter - 1;
    sum[0] = (uint128) (intermediaries[0] & (lowerMask)); // To get the lower part
    sum[1] = (uint128) (intermediaries[1] & (lowerMask) + intermediaries[0] / shifter);
    sum[2] = (uint128) (intermediaries[2] & (lowerMask) + intermediaries[1] / shifter);
    sum[3] = (uint128) (intermediaries[3] & (lowerMask) + intermediaries[2] / shifter);
    // Yes, intermediaries[3] / 2^128 is lost
}
```