# Max number of tokens possible in Solidity?

Tags: solidity

So me and one of my friends are trying create our own token using Solidity for fun. It is supposed to have a total supply of the amount of atoms in the universe. I wanted to know if it is possible to have this much data fit in a contract since normally the contracts are bound to uint256. I tried finding a solution online but couldn't really find an answer anywhere. Anyone have any idea?

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 0):

Well, that's a difficult question. As @Richard Horrocks said in his comment, your best bet is probably to use some kind of a very large integer, like here: [How to define 2048-bit integers on smart contracts?](https://ethereum.stackexchange.com/questions/62422/how-to-define-2048-bit-integers-on-smart-contracts).

Another way to deal with the issue would be this:

- Every user has a wallet, just like on every other currency
- Every wallet is divided into sub-wallets, each with a maximum balance of the maximum `uint256`
- When a sub-wallet is filled with coins, a new sub-wallet is opened

All these sub-wallets would be linked to the user's main wallet using an array of references.

This latter one not a particularly good or gas-efficient way to deal with issue, but since you're doing this for fun, it might be a lot easier to wrap your head around than the first solution